# Python 2.7: Function accessing a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am using Python2.7 with the SimPy module, first time posting here.
I am just learning both of them so I hope I explain this correctly.
The aim of my program:
Create a Demand object and generate a number weekly.
Store it in a list.
Create a Supply object and generate a number weekly, based on the number created by the demand object.
I seem to be able to create my 52 numbers, and append them to a list, but I cant succesfully get the Supply object to read through the list.
My code is as follows:

```
from SimPy.Simulation import *
import pylab as pyl
from random import Random
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Model components
runLength = 51

## Lists for examination
D1Vals = []
S1Vals = []

.... other code lines

class Demander(Process):

# This object creates the demand, and stores the values in the 'D1Vals' list above

def weeklyDemand(self):  # Demand Weekly
    while True:
            lead = 1.0      # time between demand requests
            demand = random.triangular(20,110,370)  # amount demanded each increment
            #yield put, self, orderBook, delivery
            print('Week'+'%6.0f: Need %6.0f units: Total Demand = %6.0f' %
                    (now(), demand, orderBook.amount))
            yield hold, self, lead
            yield put, self, orderBook, demand
            D1Vals.append(demand)

# This object is trying to read each value iteratively in D1Vals, 
  and create a supply value and store in a list 'S1Vals'

class Supplier(Process):

def supply_rate(self):
    lead = 1.0
    for x in D1Vals:
            supply = random.triangular(x - 30, x , x + 30)               
            yield put, self, stocked, supply
            print('Week'+'%6.0f: Gave %6.0f units: Inv. Created = %6.0f' %
                    (now(), supply,stocked.amount))
            yield hold, self, lead
            S1Vals.append(stocked.amount)

..... other misc coding .....

# Model
demand_1 = Demander()
activate(demand_1, demand_1.weeklyDemand())
supply_1 = Supplier()
activate(supply_1, supply_1.supply_rate())
simulate(until=runLength)
```

When I run my program, it creates my demand and outputs the weekly and cumulative values to the console, it also prints the D1Vals list for me to see that it is not empty.

Can anyone please guide me to the correct path for succesfully reading the list from the Supplier Object and function.
Thanks and please excuse my obvious 'fresh' outlook on python ;)

Comment: Your indentation for the supply_rate() and weeklyDemand() methods are messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`D1Vals` and `S1Vals` are defined at the module scope;
You should be able to write expressions like
`x=S1Vals[-7:]` anywhere in that module without a problem.

This works for accessing the value of and mutating the value of these variables,
so that

```
def append_supply( s ):
    S1Vals.append(s)
```

should work.

To assign to them however, you need to declare them as global

```
def erase_supply():
    '''Clear the list of supply values'''
    global S1Vals
    S1Vals = []
```

If the `global S1Vals` line is omitted, the result will be that the function-local
variable `S1Vals` is defined by the assignment statement, shadowing the module-level 
variable with the same name.

A way to avoid using the global statement is to use the actual module name 
to refer to these variables.  I'll assume that your code is defined in
`SupplyAndDemandModel.py`.

At the top of this file you can put

```
import SupplyAndDemandModel
```

and then refer to those module-scoped variables using the module name:

```
SupplyAndDemandModel.S1Vals = []
```

This provides a way of unambiguously indicating that you are accessing/modifying a module-level variable.

Comment: @Colin :  Thanks, its ok in my actual program.

Comment: @DaveThank you for your time, though it seems a bit complex for me at this stage of my learning curve. I was hoping to find a fix for my 'beginner' coding as it stands. Another thing I noticed that if I manually populate the D1Vals with any random number, then the program works (even though the len(D1Vals) is now 52 instead of 51). Going to keep trying, and still appreciate any help

Comment: @ Dave. With your advice I was able to get a result by declaring the list as a global, and every time it accessed the list , it deleted the entry. So it was a worthwhile learning exercise, as it forced me to understand where I can access variables from. Thanks. Dont know if I am meant to post the working code?